# CardView is not displayed inside a recyclerview when activity starts?

Tags: android

Here's my code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />
```

grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

onCreate in MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getpopularmovies popularmovies= new getpopularmovies();
    popularmovies.execute(); //AsyncTask
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new GridAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

When I run the app I see the black background but I don't see the cards with images. But when I turn the phone screen back and forth I see the cards. The only problem is at the start of the app. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);` instead of `mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);`

UPDATE: I tried `GridLayoutManager(this,2);`, it still works. Perhaps, you should execute `setAdapter(adapter);` after data populated (asynctask). You could try at `onPostExecute`